# WireMock Java. Can`t catch request

Tags: java, wiremock

My php project running on docker container with url localhost:8888 . I try to catch request by mock server. Using wireMock library. Java 11.

When i press some button - in development console network tab i see^

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8888/local/components/bitrix/crm.timeline/ajax.php?&site=s1&sessid=b185ff996872fca310a9484822ab7557
Request Method: POST
```

And try to catch this request with next code^

```
WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer();

    @Tag("PC")
    @RepeatedIfExceptionsTest(name = "\nОтправка Whats`up сообщения. Поле Контактный телефон заполнено.", suspend = suspend, repeats = 1)
    @TmsLink("CORP-208")
    public void whatsUpHasContactPhoneField() {
        wireMockServer.start();
        wireMockServer.stubFor(post("/local/components/bitrix/crm.timeline/ajax.php")
                .willReturn(ok()));

        page.open(crmNewDeal + "/4/");
        page.click(detailsForm.whatsapp);

        detailsForm.whatsappMessageArea.sendKeys("Test message");
        detailsForm.whatsappSendMsgBtn.click();

        verify(postRequestedFor(urlPathEqualTo("/local/components/bitrix/crm.timeline/ajax.php")));
    }
}
```

But i get as result:  Requests received: [ ]
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`new WireMockServer();` (with no parameters) will start on the default port number - 8080. You either need to point your tests to use this port or pass 8888 as the constructor parameter.

Comment: but if i put port=8888,  i got exception: port is already bind (because  i have docker container with this port)

Comment: You will need to pick a different port number for your mock API in that case

Comment: yes. i set  i set random free port. And i cant catch this request

Comment: It looks like :       WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(8787);